# Python Regex help required

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract data from a text file.
For ex in line '35 of Jon 2013 trans. (P) ' I am trying to extract (35, 2013, (P)).

In this 35 is document number and 2015 is document year, (P) denotes priority document.

Document Numbers are followed by Document year and they have (P) in end if document is of high priority.

There is possibility that a document is not of high priority and it will not contain (P) at end. 
ex - '31 of Sansa 2014 filled' 
in this I want to extract (31,2014,'')

I have a string that contain information of document. The problem is that the string is concatenated and in a single string there is information of multiple document.

line = '35 of Jon 2013 trans. (P) 31 of Sansa 2014 filled 3232 of Arya 2014 empty 345 of Bran 2011 sealed, (P) '

I have written the following code but it does not function correctly.

```
rgx = r'(\d{1,9})\s* OF \s*[A-Za-z]+\s*([1,2]\d{3}).*?(\(P\))?'
rgx2 = r'(\d{1,9})\s* OF \s*[A-Za-z]+\s*([1,2]\d{3}).*?(\(P\))'
line = '35 of Jon 2013 trans. (P) 31 of Sansa 2014 filled 3232 of Arya 2014 empty 345 of Bran 2011 sealed, (P)'

x = re.findall(rgx, line, re.IGNORECASE)
for i in x:
    print i
print 'Output by rgx2'
x = re.findall(rgx2, line, re.IGNORECASE)
for i in x:
    print i
```

Output generated by this code : -

```
('35', '2013', '')
('31', '2014', '')
('3232', '2014', '')
('345', '2011', '')
Output by rgx2
('35', '2013', '(P)')
('31', '2014', '(P)')
```

While the first regex is able to catch document id and document year correctly but it fails to extract (P) type as I am using "(P)?". 
Problem with second regex is that I am using ".*?(P)" to find P type and it results into wrong data.

The correct data output which I want is

```
 ('35', '2013', '(P)')
 ('31', '2014', '')
 ('3232', '2014', '')
 ('345', '2011', '(P)')
```

Can anyone suggest a better regex.
Please Help !

Comment: Please post a sample of the original file and how you load it. Your question is nominally about processing information from a text file, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as you want it:

```
import re

reg = r'(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d|\(]*(\(P\))*'
line = '35 of Jon 2013 trans. (P) 31 of Sansa 2014 filled 3232 of Arya 2014 empty 345 of Bran 2011 sealed, (P)'

print 'Output by reg'    
for _ in re.findall(reg, line, re.IGNORECASE):
    print _
```

Comment: Is there a certain reason you are using the pipe-character inside `[^\d|\(]`?

Comment: I think you are right and it is optional in this case but I find it more readable. I think that it is simply ignored and does not need to be used.

Comment: No it is not ignored, it is treated as the literal pipe character, thus excluded from the list of matching characters. If there is no reason to explicitly use a pipe inside a character class, you should not use it.

Comment: What I was meaning was: It is excluded from the matching characters since I use | and not \| . Nevertheless I think you are correct and it should not be used inside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
(\d+) of [a-zA-Z]+ (\d+) [a-zA-Z.]+(?:[,]? (\(P\)))?
```